# I am sharing my internet connection (Ethernet) via WI-FI but it keeps disconnecting

Tags: internet, internet-sharing

I'm sharing my internet connection (ethernet) via wi-fi but it (the wi-fi) keeps disconnecting. When I go into network settings the internet sharing box is still checked, so I have to turn it off and back on to get it to work again. Is there a way to stop it from doing this?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by “it keeps disconnecting.”  Is it  the internet, the Ethernet, and/or the WiFi that’s disconnecting?

Comment: the wifi. It can't be found until I turn it off and on again

Comment: Ok.  Is the WiFi disconnecting all clients, one client?  Please add *details;* remember we’re not able to look over your shoulder

Comment: clients?  I'm connecting to my phone and after about 20 min the connection is lost and cannot be found until it is turned off and on..

Comment: @GregMcKinney if your Ethernet uses some kind of authentication, it is expected. Though annoying.

Comment: You're connecting to your phone..ok.  You are on your phone connecting to the Internet via WiFi and after 20 minutes, Internet stops working.  You then have to "turn it on/off"  Correct?  What does "it" refer to?  Your phone's WiFi or your laptop's WiFi?  Also, please provide model(s) and OS levels.